# Shell says find: missing argument to `-exec' and no alternatives working

Tags: windows, shell, find, rm

A backup program I used recently made duplicates of whole bunch of files throughout my computer because of some setting that I've since changed.

When the backup program made a copy, it renamed the old one `original1.thefilename.extension`. I'm trying to automatically delete all of these unnecessary files with a simple shell command.

```
 find -type f -name 'original1*' -exec rm {} \;
```

However, when I try to run this I get

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I've looked all over the web for a solution. I've found suggestions that I should try `exec rm +`, `-exec rm {} +`, `-exec rm {} \;`, `-exec rm +` etc. but none of them work. I am using Windows 8.1

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I have to ask ... are you using a windows command shell? Or Cygwin? Running a Unix VM? Or are you connected to a Unix server somewhere else? I'm confused by the "I am using Windows 8.1" statement.

Comment: If you're using Windows 8.1, which version of `find` are you using?  Cygwin?  MinGW?  Some other version?  It would be sensible to tag the question with the environment name.  Which shell are you using?  What happens if you use `\{\}` or `'{}'` or `"{}"` instead of just `{}`?

Comment: I'm using Cmder, and using a `cmd` window

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `find --version` returns `GNU find version 4.1`

Comment: But you're using a cmd.exe shell and window?  Or are you using some other terminal that looks a bit like a cmd.exe window and running a shell in it?  I've not come across 'Cmder', but that may simply mean I'm not paying attention to Windows (which is accurate). That said, a Google search for 'cmder' finds it easily enough. I'm not clear which shell language it supports, though. I suspect that `{}` is some sort of metacharacter to the shell and needs to be escaped. In some circumstances, Bash will interpret `{0..9}` as the values 0 through 9, for example. Maybe something like that is happening.

Comment: Following your hints I installed `cygwin` and using the same command as I was trying before, it works!

Answer (score 4):

In Windows command shell, you don't need to escape the semicolon.

```
find -type f -name 'original1*' -exec rm {} ;
```

Your version of the command should work in a bash shell (like cygwin).

It's interesting that you get the gnu `find` to execute, because on my Windows 8.1 machine, I get Microsoft's `find`.